# how to join 4 table or more in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

this my model and my function

```
 function all($npp,$nama_pegawai,$jenis_jabatan,$nama_cabang,$nama_unit,$nama) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('pegawai');
             $this->db->join('nama_cabang','cabang.kd_cabang=pegawai.kd_cabang');
              $this->db->join                  ('nama_unit','unit_kerja.kd_unit=pegawai.kd_unit');
                              $this->db->join   ('nama','jabatan.kd_jabatan=pegawai.kd_jabatan');
                                 $this->db->join('jenis_jabatan','jenis_jabatan.kd_jenis=jabatan.kd_jenis');



            if($npp!=""){
            $this->db->like('npp',$npp);    
            }    


            if($nama_pegawai!=""){
            $this->db->where('nama_pegawai',$nama_pegawai);
            } 
             if($jenis_jabatan!=""){
            $this->db->where('jenis_jabatan.jenis_jabatan',$jenis_jabatan);
            } 
             if($nama_cabang!=""){
            $this->db->where('cabang.nama_cabang',$nama_cabang);
            } 
             if($nama_unit!=""){
            $this->db->where('unit_kerja.nama_unit',$nama_unit);
            } 
             if($nama!=""){
            $this->db->where('jabatan.nama',$nama);
            }     

            return  $this->db->get();
            }
```

this my controller

```
 public function index()
        { 
        if($this->session->userdata('LOGIN')=='TRUE')
     if($this->session->userdata('STATUS')==0){

   $data['judul']='Table Master Cuti namaanan';

        $npp = $this->input->get('npp');
    $nama_pegawai = $this->input->get('nama_pegawai');
     $nama_cabang = $this->input->get('nama_pegawai');
      $nama_unit = $this->input->get('nama_pegawai');
       $nama = $this->input->get('nama');
  $jenis_jabatan = $this->input->get('jenis_jabatan');




        $per_page = abs($this->input->get('per_page'));
        $limit = 10;
        $tot = $this->pegawai_Model->all($npp,$nama_pegawai,$jenis_jabatan,$nama_cabang,$nama_unit,$nama);
        $data['npp']   = $this->pegawai_Model->limit($npp,$nama_pegawai,$jenis_jabatan,$nama_cabang,$nama_unit,$nama, $limit, $per_page);


         $data['nama_pegawai']   = $this->pegawai_Model->nama_pegawai();
          $data['nama_cabang']   = $this->pegawai_Model->nama_cabang();
           $data['nama_unit']   = $this->pegawai_Model->nama_unit();
            $data['nama']   = $this->pegawai_Model->nama();
           $data['jenis_pegawai']   = $this->pegawai_Model->jenis_jabatan();
```

and this my error

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

Table 'cutionline.nama_cabang' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`pegawai`) JOIN `nama_cabang` ON `cabang`.`kd_cabang`=`pegawai`.`kd_cabang` JOIN `nama_unit` ON `unit_kerja`.`kd_unit`=`pegawai`.`kd_unit` JOIN `nama` ON `jabatan`.`kd_jabatan`=`pegawai`.`kd_jabatan` JOIN `jenis_jabatan` ON `jenis_jabatan`.`kd_jenis`=`jabatan`.`kd_jenis`

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\jasamarga\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: What happens when you run that query in PMA? But the error your getting means that you don't have a table that you are trying to query

Comment: If the `nama_cabang` dies not exist in your database, then you don't have a codeigniter problem, you have a database schema problem.  Only by fixing your database can you begin to analyze the correctness of your php script.  @Faza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.ID = table1.ID');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table3.ID = table1.ID');
$this->db->join('table4', 'table4.ID = table1.ID', 'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pegawai');
$this->db->join('cabang as a', 'a.kd_cabang = pegawai.kd_cabang', 'left');
$this->db->join('unit_kerja as b', 'b.kd_unit = pegawai.kd_unit', 'left');
$this->db->join('jenis_jabatan as d', 'd.kd_jenis = pegawai.kd_jenis', 'left');
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.